# Extending/scaling graph network based on independent nodes using NetworkX

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, graph-theory, directed-graph

I have two separate lists of nodes and stations. Each list consists of Node (or station) ID, x-coordinate, and y-coordinate. I pick up a random set of nodes and connect them to generate a graph network using NetworkX based on a certain distance between them. I select a random set of stations. I have shared the data and code at [Data and Code](https://github.com/BabarShahzaad/SampleData.git)

Now, I want to extend the graph network in a way that each edge should be within a certain distance from the station. I want to keep the shape (topology) of the initial network as it is but want to zoom (or scale/extend) the network to make it close to the stations. I am not sure how can I extend the graph to meet the aforementioned conditions/constraints. The stations can be regarded as forming an overlay network and the base network is being extended based on this overlay network. Here is a figure to show the desired network. Any help in this regard is very much appreciated.

[Network Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sb19z.png)

Comment: As it's written, it's not clear what you are asking.  It would be helpful to include some code and sample data to make your description more concrete.

Comment: @Frodnar Thank you. I have edited my question and added the link for the data and code I have tried so far. Can you please have a look at it and suggest some directions?